# What is the scope of a Java variable in a block?

Tags: java, variables, scope

I know in C++ variables have block scope, for example, the following code works in C++:

```
void foo(){
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        int a = 1; // Redefine a here.
    }
}
```

But this snippet doesn't work in Java, it reports "duplicate local variable a", does it mean Java variables don't have BLOCK scope?

Comment: Good extended discussion about this can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141140/why-does-java-not-have-block-scoped-variable-declarations

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? A compiler error or warning, or ...? Please try to be precise with your descriptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

java variables do have a block scope but if you notice int a is already defined in scope

```
  { 
     int a = 0;
      {
       {
        } 
      }




   }
```

all subscopes are in scope of the uppermost curly braces. Hence you get a duplicate variable error.

Answer (score 10):

They have block scope. That means that you can't use them outside of the block. However Java disallows hiding a name in the outer block by a name in the inner one.

Answer (score 4):

[`Section §14.4.2`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/statements.doc.html#32644) says:

> The scope of a local variable
>   declaration in a block (§14.2) is the
>   rest of the block in which the
>   declaration appears, starting with its
>   own initializer (§14.4) and including
>   any further declarators to the right
>   in the local variable declaration
>   statement.
>
> The name of a local variable v may **not**
>   be redeclared as a local variable of
>   the directly enclosing method,
>   constructor or **initializer block**
>   within the scope of v, or a
>   compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers already stated the reason, but I just want to show that this is still allowed:

```
void foo(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        int a = 1;
    }
    int a = 0;
}
```

In this case the `a` inside the loop doesn't hide the outer `a`, so it's valid.

Also IMHO it should be this way in C++ too, it's less confusing and prevents accidental declaration of variable with same name.

Answer (score 2):

It does, but it's nested, so the "a" you defined in foo() is available in all blocks within foo.

Here is an example of what you're looking for:

```
void foo(){
    {
        int a = 0;
        // Do something with a
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        int a = 1; //define a here.
    }
}
```