# Variables with the same name inside Some(T) in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm fairly new to Rust so I came across this piece of code in the official [Guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/guide.html#comparing-guesses)

```
let input = io::stdin().read_line()
                       .ok()
                       .expect("Failed to read line");
let input_num: Option<uint> = from_str(input.as_slice());

let num = match input_num {
    Some(num) => num,
    None      => {
        println!("Please input a number!");
        return;
    }
};
```

While the understand the first two statements (on `input` and `inputnum`), I'm not quite sure about the match statement. So I checked the [documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#variant.Some) which shows that `Option<T>` can take two values , either `None` or `Some(T)` for some (object?) `T`. So I tested the following code:

```
io::println( 
    match input_num {
        Some(num) => "somenum",
        None      => {
            println!("Please input a number only!");
            return;
        }
    }
);
```

This code works as expected; it prints `somenum` if you enter a number and otherwise it prints the error message. However, the compiler gives a warning stating: `warning: unused variable:`num`, #[warn(unused_variable)] on by default`. This confirmed my suspicions that the `num` inside the `match is used as a variable.

**Question:** How is it possible that `rust` does not complain about (in the Guide's example) having two variables with the same name `num`? Or does it "hand over" the pointer to the inside `num` to the outside `num`? 
Also in the case of an empty `return` what exactly is returned? I'm guessing it is unit `()` because it is mentioned [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/unit/index.html) that

> functions without a `-> ...` implicitly have return type `()`

**Edit:** Sorry for missing the obvious point. The `return` directly exits the function without bothering to put anything into `num`.

P.S. I noticed that using `cargo build` to compile does not give warnings the second time around (not making any changes). Does `cargo` keep tracking of versions or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any experiences with Java or C#?  Many mainstream programing languages allows you to [shadow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) a variable with another variable with the same name in a new block scope.  For example, take a look at this C# code:

```c#
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int x = 10;
        {
            int x = 20;
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

- http://ideone.com/OuMlc8

In fact Rust is more flexible in terms of shadowing: you can shadow variables as many times as you want without explicitly making a brace block.

```
fn main() {
    let i = 10i32;
    let i = "foo";
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

- http://is.gd/CUHUOL

Here, the first `i` and the second `i` have no relationships.  We just lose a way to use (refer to) the first `i`.

> This confirmed my suspicions that the num inside the `match is used as a variable.

Yes, pattern matching can introduce new variables.  But the new variable `num` introduced by pattern matching has no direct relationship with the outer `num` whose value is being given by the `match` expression.

I can translate your Rust code into less idiomatic Rust to illustrate what was happening:

```
let num =
    if input_num.is_some() {
        let num = input_num.unwrap();
        num
    } else {
        println!("Please input a number!");
        return;
    }
;
```

As for not observing warnings from `cargo build`, I suspect it was because Cargo had already built `.o` from your code and didn't bother to repeat the same job twice, knowing that there was no change in your code.

Comment: In 9 months of Java programming, I hadn't encountered a single example of shadowing. Perhaps because it is a bit confusing. Thanks for the links and extra information.

Comment: Hmm, I found Java is indeed much less permissive with shadowing  http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/07/07/variable-shadowing/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623334/question-about-variable-scope-and-shadowing-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141140/why-does-java-not-have-block-scoped-variable-declarations No wonder you haven't had any chances to encounter it.

Comment: In Rust you have pattern matching and everything-is-an-expression doctrine. These nudge you towards instances of name shadowing. Java doesn’t have either, so it’s no surprise that you don’t get as much shadowing happening.